# Java JPanel GroupLayout formatting problem

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grouplayout

I am trying to layout my JPanel such that:

- The information label is at the top,
- The text area is directly below, **this and the info label go across (horizontally) the entire panel**,
- Below the text from left to right (equally spaced) are the config, save and then clear buttons,
- Below those is the success/failure label (central, under the save button) and the home button (right, under the clear button).

I have tried many combinations and used other stack answers but cannot get it right, something about group layout I can't get my head around!

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameTest {
    private static JFrame mainApp;
    private static JPanel mainPanel;

public JFrameTest() {
        mainApp = new JFrame("Application");
        mainApp.setSize(640, 480);
        mainApp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainApp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainApp.add(mainPanel());
        mainApp.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel mainPanel() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        mainPanel= new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setSize(600,450);
        Container container = mainApp.getContentPane();
        
        JLabel labelInfo = new JLabel("add necessary information here");
        JLabel labelSOrF = new JLabel("Success/Failure");
        //    labelSOrF.setVisible(false);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

        JButton configButton= new JButton("config");
        JButton saveButton= new JButton("save");
        JButton clearButton= new JButton("clear");
        JButton homeButton= new JButton("Home");

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(container);
        container.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addComponent(configButton)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addComponent(saveButton)
                            .addComponent(labelSOrF, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addComponent(clearButton)
                            .addComponent(homeButton)
                    .addComponent(labelInfo)
                    .addComponent(textArea, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    )))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(labelInfo)
                    .addComponent(textArea, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(configButton)
                                    .addComponent(saveButton)
                                    .addComponent(buttonClear))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addComponent(labelSOrF, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(homeButton)))
        );
```

edit - added code

Comment: Does it have to be `GroupLayout`? Because there are much easier to use layout manager than `GroupLayout`

Comment: Yes please. For future use what other layout managers are there?

Comment: [A few](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). If you are only getting started, I would suggest `BorderLayout` which I find easy to use

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into them! Any advice on this GroupLayout problem?

Comment: Probably only with nesting, though that will make alignments a bit harder. Basically you create multiple `JPanel` and next them in each other. Each panel contains only a subset of components

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

GroupLayout was designed for GUI builders. No human being will deliberately use a GroupLayout. It's too hard to understand and as you've discovered, maintain.

Here's a GUI that meets your requirements.

[image: Application]

Swing was designed to be constructed from the inside out.  You layout the Swing components and let the `JPanels` and the `JFrame` size themselves.  You don't start with the JFrame and fit all the Swing components.

All Swing applications **must start** with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a main `JPanel` with three subordinate `JPanels`.  To construct a complex GUI, you nest simple `JPanels`.

I added the Swing components to each `JPanel` in column, row order.  That helps me to organize the code and makes it easier for readers of your code to understand the code.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JFrameTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JFrameTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame mainApp = new JFrame("Application");
        mainApp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainApp.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainApp.pack();
        mainApp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainApp.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        
        panel.add(createTitlePanel());
        panel.add(createTextAreaPanel());
        panel.add(createButtonPanel());

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createTitlePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel labelInfo = new JLabel("add necessary information here");
        panel.add(labelInfo);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createTextAreaPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 40);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3, 20, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton configButton = new JButton("config");
        panel.add(configButton);

        JButton saveButton = new JButton("save");
        panel.add(saveButton);

        JButton clearButton = new JButton("clear");
        panel.add(clearButton);
        
        JLabel dummy = new JLabel(" ");
        panel.add(dummy);

        JLabel labelSOrF = new JLabel("Success/Failure");
        panel.add(labelSOrF);

        JButton homeButton = new JButton("Home");
        panel.add(homeButton);

        return panel;
    }

}
```